# Rank() in mysql using CTE

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb, ranking

After doing research and finding that MariaDB supports Common Table Expressions (CTE), I tried to rank as such but getting an error:

3 errors were found during analysis.

- An alias was previously found. (near "position" at position 183)
- An alias was expected. (near " " at position 182)
- Unrecognized keyword. (near "position" at position 183)

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(PARTITION BY year ORDER BY sale DESC ) position FROM sales LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

So I'm guessing the error is just after rank. What is wrong. Here is my code.

the table columns are

```
employee | year | sale
----------------------
```

```
SELECT
employee,
year,
sale,
RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY
                 year
             ORDER BY
                 sale DESC
            ) position
FROM
sales;
```

Comment: What is your MariaDB version?

Comment: version 10.1.31

Comment: This has made me realize that I'm using a version not supported

Comment: You do realize that OVER is a windowing function keyword and not a CTE.  BTW Both CTEs and Windowing Functions are in MySQL 8 also.

Comment: That's also not a CTE.

Comment: I think there was so much to explain which is not possible within a question so generalization was important for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

Incase someone encounters the same problem, know that CTE are only supported from version 10.2

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to `rank()` with a correlated subquery is:

```
select s.*,
       (select count(*) + 1
        from sales s2
        where s2.year = s.year and s2.sale > s.sale
       ) as position
from sales s;
```